# Managing Events in Shotwell

Tags: shotwell, events

Running Shotwell 0.20.2.

Shotwell recognizes events based on the date of the photo.

I have three cases where this leads to problem:

- Multiple events on the same day. A family outing in the morning, catching up with friends in the evening
- An event spanning multiple days. A workshop across three days
- Collections. Photos of birds takes on different dates that I want to see at one place

I can use tags/folders to organize photos the way I want. But how do I get it done within the 'Events' framework in Shotwell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first case (multiple events on the same day), there's a workaround:

1. Select photos from a specific event.
2. Go to Events menu->New event (or press CTRL+N).

A new event will be created with the same date, but just with the photos you choosed. Rename it as you like, and repeat for each event in the day.

Answer (score 6):

*An event spanning multiple days. A workshop across three days*

1. Select the month in the event navigator
2. Mark the related events in the right pane
3. In the menu bar: Events > Merge Events
4. Rename the event

But unfortunately I have no idea for the other cases. Maybe you should use [digiKam](https://www.digikam.org/) or [darktable](http://www.darktable.org/).

Comment: Thanks! This works nicely. Hope there are answers for the other two cases. (I have edited the question to add one more case)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea for the other cases.

Comment: Actually you can use the same approach for all the cases although tags might be easier for collections. For multiple events on the same day you can Add an event for a specific day and select the photos that belong to that event. Merging isn't required in this case.  See: http://www.linuceum.com/Desktop/Shotwell.php

Answer (score 3):

As for Collections (photos on different dates that you want to see together), you can always create an event (for example with the first photo in the collection) and then drag all remaining photos to this newly created event.

You will lose somewhat the perception of dates (the full collection will show in a specific day until you open it), but since the theme is probably more important than the date, perhaps it's not such a big deal.